# How to update existing object inside an array using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord.js

I'm trying to make a currency system with my discord.js bot and mongoose. Here is an example MongoDB document format:

```json
{
  guild: "2095843098435435435",
  wallets: [
    {
      id: "2323232335354",
      amount: 10,
    },
    {
      id: "24344343234454",
      amount: "i want to update this",
    },
  ],
};
```

As far as I know, the [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function is for making a new object inside an array.

But how can I update an existing object inside an array?

My code:

```js
const find = await Account.findOne({
  guild: message.guild.id,
});

if (!find) return message.channel.send("...");

const memberRole = message.guild.members.cache
  .find((x) => x.id === message.author.id)
  .roles.cache.find(
    (x) =>
      x.name.toLowerCase() === "tournament manager" ||
      x.name.toLowerCase() === "events staff" ||
      x.name.toLowerCase() === "wallet manager"
  );

if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR") || memberRole) {
  if (!args[2]) return message.reply("...");

  const mention = message.mentions.users.first();
  if (!mention) return message.reply("...");

  const account = find.wallets.find((x) => x.id === mention.id);
  if (!account) return message.reply("...");
  if (!args[3]) return message.reply("...");

  if (isNaN(args[3])) return message.channel.send("...");
  const update = account.update({
    amount: (account.amount += args[3]),
  });
  await find.save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$set` Operator to update your collection something like this will help

```
db.collection.update({"wallets.id": "24344343234454"},{$set: {
        "wallets.$.amount": "This is new_value"
    }}
```

You can read more about [$set here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/).

The `$` sign is the positional operator that will hold the position(index) of array item matched in first expression. More about [positional operator here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

Comment: "This is new_value"

My current value is set to ```account.amount += args[3]``` but i dont know now what should i replace with account. should it be ```wallets.amount``` or ```find.wallets.amount```

Comment: # wait buddy, this is mongoose which is i am using,  mongoose npm pack, not mongodb